# Same kafka topic for multiple table records

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I've several orders databases (Ex: OrderUSA, OrderUK, OrderIndia,...) in postgres, all the database will have the same schema and tables. I want to merge all the `tbl_orders` from these databases into one. I am writing debezium connectors for each database. Is possible to use the same topic for all these debezium connectors? It will be easy for me to have one topic which will have consolidated data. Then I could use the topic for the sink connector. Please advise so that I could move this model to production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have one topic containing data for all databases.

Whether you should do that, well it depends. This reddit post may be helpful to you: https://www.reddit.com/r/apachekafka/comments/q8a7sj/topic_strategies_when_to_split_into_multiple/

Ultimately, it depends on your business requirements and whether it is logical for all order data to be in one topic.

Comment: Thanks @Jessica Vasey . I've proceeded in this way (one topics for all database data),  things are working fine until now

Comment: Hi @Alphonse thanks for the update. Would you want your consumers to consume all the data i.e. all order databases?

Comment: yes @Jessica Vasey, I will use this single topic for the kafka-jdbc-sink connector. This will update my table in the data warehouse , which will be used for reports and dashboards.